# Calculating percentages and rates when there is duplicate data.

Tags: statistics, percentages, related-rates

I have 2 types of computers A and B in a data center. Each type has multiple computers. Hardware components in these computers keep failing. I collect data for about a year on how many parts fail.

Total computers of type A -> 80

Total computers of type B -> 65

Total failures in type A -> 50

Total failures in type B -> 36

If there are around 50 total failures in different computers of type A and
36 total failures in different computers of type B,
How can I represent them as percentages?

Would it be right to just do 50/80 and 36/65 to get the failure rate? I ask this because out of 50 the failures, a single computer might have had multiple failures.
If that is the case, would it be logically correct to just calculate
(Number of failures in type A)/(Total number of computers of type A)

If the above method is indeed correct, and suppose my failures in a particular year go up to 100, would it still make sense to report 100/80 as
the failure rate for type A?

Comment: There is some ambiguity in this. What do you want the failure rate to tell you? The likelihood that any single computer of each type will fail? The number of failures per computer of each type? The answer you choose depends on what type of information you want.

Comment: What is it that you intend to do with this data?

Comment: Depends on whether you want failure percentage for each Computer or failure rate per year for each Type.